# How to make list items the same width

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I have a list of fields, where each field can have multiple values.
There is a span for the field name, and then a span for each field value.

In case that a field name is longer than the minimum value, I want all of the fields to have the same width. Is there a way I can achieve this without turning it into a table?

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of list | keyvalue">
    <span class="field">{{ item.key }}</span>
    <span
      class="value"
      *ngFor="let value of item.value"
      >{{ value }} 
      <br/></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;

  li {
      padding: 5px 0;
      display: flex;

      &:not(:last-child) {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      }
    
      .field {
        min-width: 120px;
        padding-right: 8px;
      }
  }
}
```

I tried using max-content and playing around with flexbox, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Helps to adding all code that reproduces the problem in a stack snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can style it as a grid.

```css
ul {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  gap: 0.5em 1em;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: contents;    /* allow the spans to populate the grid instead of the list items */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="field">Key 1</span>
    <span class="value">Red, Blue, Green</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="field">Key 2</span>
    <span class="value">Orange, Pink, Black</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="field">Key 3 is the longest</span>
    <span class="value">Purple, Yellow, Brown</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It’s even simpler if you mark it up as a [description list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) instead of an unordered list:

```css
dl {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  gap: 0.5em 1em;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

dd {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Key 1</dt>
  <dd>Red, Blue, Green</dd>
  
  <dt>Key 2</dt>
  <dd>Orange, Pink, Black</dd>

  <dt>Key 3 is the longest</dt>
  <dd>Purple, Yellow, Brown</dd>
</dl>
```